# Why won't grub load my newly upgraded kernel?

Tags: boot, upgrade, grub2, kernel, updates

I upgrade my kernel

when I run update-grub, these are found

```
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-3-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-20-generic
Found GRUB 2: /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

but when run `uname -r`, the kernel is `3.0.0-20`.

How can I solve that?

Comment: You have tagged your question with [tag:grub2] but GRUB is updating `menu.lst`. Are you still using GRUB 1? What is the version number shown on your GRUB boot menu? [**screenshot**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9AGyg.png)

Comment: I retagged, it appears this may be an installation upgraded more than once, with the original install using grub1? Because grub2 is also installed (see line 6).

Answer (score 2):

> but when run `uname -r`, the kernel is 3.0.0-20. How can I solve that?

REBOOT!

When you upgrade the kernel, you must [usually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) reboot to switch to the new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was to install GRUB2 because I was using grub 0.97. after you install grub2, update-grub and reboot the new kernel will be listed in the boot menu.